# Object not fetch well in java

Tags: jakarta-ee, jpa, fetch

I have a problem with fetching objects in Java. There is object A which is Entity bean class and it contains object B (other Entity bean class) as a field. Object A was created without B and later object B was attached to A with some action.
Problem is that some users can not see object B in object A, it looks like null. In database everything is fine and after some time object A looks good (contains B). This happens only in some cases, in other object looks good from begin.
I want to say that we use two virtual machines for running application (maybe it can be problem) and Oracle Application Server.
Any help?
Stojan

Code looks like:
Entity class A is defined like this (B is also entity class).

```
 @Entity
 @Table(name = "A")
 public class A{
     ...
     @ManyToOne
     @JoinColumn(name="ID_B", referencedColumnName="ID")
     private B b;
     ...
 }
```

Object of class A is created in some action, for example:

```
public createA_action(){
     A a = new A();
     saveObject(a);
}
```

where 'saveObject' is some method that persist or merge object in database.

Later, there is call of other method, like this:

```
public addBtoA_action(){
     A a = getA();
     B b = getB();
     a.setB(b);
     saveObject(a);
}
```

where getA() and getB() get an existing objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the problem.
Like I said before, I am using two virtual machines. Like Gab said before, every virtual machine has it's own cache.
Scenario: user1 is using virtual machine 1 (VM1) and the other user (user2) is using VM2 and both of them see created object (after first transaction). After that user1 changes the object (second transaction). User2 will not see that change because cache of VM2 have an old object.
Solution: I am using NativeQuery to get the ids from database and method that get object by id. I put EntityManager.refresh() in the method that got the object from the database and everything works fine.
So, before change, I got objects from the ids with method like:

```
public Object getObj(Long id, Class class){
    return em.find(class, id);
}
```

After the change, this method looks like:

```
public Object getObj(Long id, Class class){
    Object obj = em.find(class, id);
    em.refresh(obj);
    return obj;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, each entityManager (session in hibernate) has his own in-memory instances of the entity. Generally you have one EntityManager per transaction and one transaction per http-request.

So if One entity instance was loaded in a given transaction t1 and then loaded in another transaction t2, if you set the 'a' field on this entity in t1, then  you won't be able to see the modification in t2 until t1 is **commited** * and the EntityManager.refresh() method is called on the given entity.

* Transaction isolation level in JPA is read_commited

Comment: Hi Gab.  
Thanks for your answer.  
I know there will be problem if I do two transactions in the same time. But in my case one transaction happened (and commited) about 10 minutes before the other. I think that EntityManager must refresh after the transaction is commited but it looks that doesn't happen. Also there is query to get object before call of second transaction, so the object can not be old. Am I right?  
Of course, EntityManager.refresh() resolve the problem but I want to know why it happens.

Comment: Depending the way you execute the query but it may hit the n1 cache (EntityManager) instead of database.

Comment: Thanks on fast answer. I also think that cache is problem. Is there any way to avoid using cache and how it will affect application's performance (if you have experience with that)?

Comment: There is 2 caches in jpa. L1 (entityManager currently managed entities) and l2 (shared cache). You can't disable l1 cache. If I remember well, only namedQuery hit the caches (I'am not sure about that). Native query always bypass all caches. You have many configuration option (queryHints, etc...).
See http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Caching and http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Development/JPA_2.0/cache_usaged

Comment: If I correctly understood your case, you retrieve and entity in t1, then t2 update and commit it, and you'd like change to be available in t1. If yes, refresh() is the right way here. Anyway if you keep an EntityManager (means generally a transaction) opened during 10 minutes, you may have a design problem, otherwise you should at least set up optimistic locking.

Comment: I am always using native queries. My case is nothing special. First transaction creates an object and finish. Then the object is shown in application and users use them regularly. After some time (10 minutes) one of the users change the object (second transaction). After that object still looks like before second transaction for some period of time (about 30 minutes or so) and then refresh. My application is not new. Everything was fine for about 4 years and now happen that problem for the first time. Any change was switching from one to two virtual machines and increasing number of users.

Comment: are you using a l2 (shared) cache ? This last is hold at EntityManagerFactory level, which means you will have 1 cache instances per Jee container id est per VM. Once again If you retrieve the entity using native query then you bypass all cache levels.

Comment: I don't know. I will check that. Thanks on idea.